# Error while reading file using resume_parser

Tags: python, resume, tika-server

Getting Tika Server Jar file error while reading the file using resume_parser python module. File format is pdf/doc/docx. Its throwing a warning:

```
2021-05-22 18:12:05,899 [MainThread  ] [INFO ]  Retrieving http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/tika/tika-server/1.24/tika-server-1.24.jar.md5 to C:\Users\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\tika-server.jar.md5.
INFO:tika.tika:Retrieving http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/tika/tika-server/1.24/tika-server-1.24.jar.md5 to C:\Users\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\tika-server.jar.md5.
ERROR:root:Error in docx file:: <urlopen error [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
```

Python Script

```
from resume_parser import resumeparse

data = resumeparse.read_file(file)
```

1. Tried setting up environment variable as below: It didn't work.

TIKA_SERVER_JAR = http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/tika/tika-server/1.24/tika-server-1.24.jar.

2. Tried downloading the jar file and have set that path in the environment variable, this also didn't work.

Expected Output is dictionary with the details from the resume like email, skills, phone numbers, Universities, Company Info etc.,

It worked for the first couple of times and then I am getting this error.